# What is the best alternative for @ConfigurationProperties locations?

Tags: spring-boot

`@ConfigurationProperties` `locations` is deprecated in Spring Boot `1.4.x` and option is now removed in `1.5.x`

I was using it like this: [`BucketTestConfig.java`](https://github.com/izeye/spring-boot-throwaway-branches/blob/yaml/src/main/java/com/izeye/throwaway/config/BucketTestConfig.java#L19)

For now with deprecation, I'm trying to set the system property `spring.config.location` for both [production code](https://github.com/izeye/spring-boot-throwaway-branches/blob/yaml/src/main/java/com/izeye/throwaway/Application.java#L19) and [test code](https://github.com/izeye/spring-boot-throwaway-branches/blob/yaml/src/test/java/com/izeye/throwaway/repository/BucketTestRepositoryTests.java#L22) as an alternative.

`./gradlew clean test` is still failing although I set the system property.

What is the best alternative for deprecated `@ConfigurationProperties` `locations` in this case?

### UPDATE:

Using [`SpringApplicationBuilder.properties()`](https://github.com/izeye/spring-boot-throwaway-branches/tree/yaml-properties) doesn't work in the test (`BucketTestRepositoryTests`).

Using [`SpringApplicationBuilder.listeners()`](https://github.com/izeye/spring-boot-throwaway-branches/tree/yaml-listeners) doesn't work in the test (`BucketTestRepositoryTests`), either.

### UPDATE (2nd):

There was no reason to depend on `@ConfigurationProperties` in my case, so I went with `Yaml` instead as follows: https://github.com/izeye/spring-boot-throwaway-branches/commit/a1290672dceea98706b1a258f8a17e2628ea01ee

So this question's title is invalid and this question can be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

[Follow this thread for more information.](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6220)

Basically, this thread suggests two options

First option is to set `spring.config.name` to a list of the files you want to load:

```
new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
    .properties("spring.config.name=application,mine")
    .run(args);
```

Second options is to add listeners

```
new SpringApplicationBuilder(SanityCheckApplication.class)
    .listeners(new LoadAdditionalProperties())
    .run(args);
```

Content of `LoadAdditionalProperties`

```
@Component
public class LoadAdditionalProperties implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent> {

    private ResourceLoader loader = new DefaultResourceLoader();

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent event) {
        try {
            Resource resource = loader.getResource("classpath:mine.properties");
            PropertySource<?> propertySource = new PropertySourcesLoader().load(resource);
            event.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addLast(propertySource);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks but your referenced two options don't work for me in the test and that's why I used the system property in both the production code and the test code. I've updated my question about it.